# how to do system maintenance scheduled event in ec2 manually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using `AWS t1 micro instance` to run some webservices of my application (`LAMP server`). And also one admin panel is there running with SQLite DB.

Now I had overtaken my free tier limit. I have given a scheduled event as system maintenance, my instance is ebs backed, I want to do it manually before schedule. It is shown as system maintenance. Is it instance reboot or system reboot? I am getting confused.

Can anybody help me in achieving this manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the instance in the AWS console. Under "Instance Lifecycle", select "Stop". Wait for the instance to stop by refreshing the console or waiting for it to refresh. Once it's in "stopped" state, right click on the instance again, and click "Start". Note: this is *not* an operating system reboot. You're actually stopping the reserved instance in the hypervisor and bringing it back up, which should route it to new hardware.

The instance will come up on new hardware, and you'll have manually "scheduled" the maintenance.

This is also how you'd increase the instance size, if you ever wanted more power than a `t1.micro`. You'd stop the instance, "Change Instance Type", and start it again.

Comment: @instancereboot is it instance reboot?.in the hint it is shwn as network maintenence and power maintenence.when i search i found that instance reboot is need to be done,can u help me to clear on this.

Comment: @hacker: Yes. Stopping the instance and starting the instance again will reboot it. You could also use the "Reboot" command in the same menu in the console.